# Чем отличаются слова "обычно" и "по обыкновению" по значению и по грамматической функции?

Tags: лексика, семантика, вводные-слова, наречия

1. Оба слова входят в **синонимичный** ряд:  *обыкновенно, привычно,
   как обычно, как правило,  по большей части, чаще всего.* Но чем они **отличаются** по значению?
2. "По обыкновению" считается **вводным словом,** хотя в текстах часто не обособляется (переход в наречие). "Обычно" считают только **наречием,** в то же время его семантика подходит **к теме** вводных слов. Тогда на основании чего такое **разное** отношение?
3. Может ли "обычно" обособляться в **начале** предложения (эта позиция характерна для вводных слов)?

Answer (score 1):

1. "Обычно" обладает максимальной широтой применения. "По (своему) обыкновению" используют там, где за подлежащим стоит человек или иное живое существо:
   *По своему обыкновению, он молчал и прятал взгляд. По обыкновению, Мурка приветствовала меня довольным урчанием. Обычно в это время уже бывает морозно. Обычно он не опаздывает.*
   Я обратил ваше внимание на особенности словоупотребления, а не на разницу в значениях. Вероятно, впрочем, вы именно это подразумевали.
2. Либо я вас не понял, либо в вашем замечании - ответ на ваш вопрос. Эти две единицы схожи и по функции, и по семантике.
3. По-моему, в современных художественных текстах на РЯ это не принято, и выделение "обычно" в начале предложения будет восприниматься большинством носителей языка как стилистическая ошибка или, с натяжкой,  как проявление избыточного пуризма. Если же вы прибавите "**как** обычно," то запятая станет обязательной: **Как обычно,** она проснулась в прекрасном настроении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, разницу в значении слов я поняла (голос за это). Но мне важнее вот что. В правилах  наречие "обычно" вводным не считается, поэтому  я не могу указать правило. А без конкретной ссылки решение не будет зачтено.  С другой стороны, вводность — это синтаксическая функция, а не отнесенность  к определенной грамматической категории. Поэтому мне хотелось бы сослаться на практику письма. Встречается ли обособление наречия "обычно" в начале предложения в худож.  текстах. Бывают случаи,  когда обособление требуется по структуре  предложения.  Вот такие примеры меня интересуют.

Comment: @Sharon Мне встречались "Словари языка Пушкина (Достоевского и др)". Думается, есть и движки по поиску слов в соответствующих ПСС. Важно помнить о том, что качество оцифровки текстов (когда машинистка набирает текст книги и выкладывает её в интернет при минимальной и третьесортной вычитке и редактировании) резко падает в последние годы: это касается и пунктуации, и орфографии, и грамматики, и т.д., и т.п.

Comment: Тогда сами придумайте "художественный" текст)) (Можно придумать сначала модель предложения, где такой вариант возможен.) Конечно, в большинстве случаев обособлять не надо, но и запрета на обособление я тоже не вижу. Другими словами, никогда не говори никогда.

Answer (score 0):

*Обычно* — обстоятельство образа действия, как и *по обыкновению*, но по значению они, конечно, не синонимы. Скорее *по обыкновению* синоним с *как обычно*, а *обычно* синоним с *чаще всего*.

Синтаксическая функция у них различается, *обычно* — обычно детерминант, а *по обыкновению* — обычное наречие.

*Обычно* не считается вводным словом. Сравним его с таким же детерминантом *действительно*, который всегда можно трактовать и как вводное, и как невводное. Разница между ними только в отношении к утверждению, *действительно* более похоже на внешнее вводное. Но я сторонник синтаксической вводности, а не семантической. То есть, если можно считать слова невводными, то они невводные, у меня действительно никогда не вводное.

Comment: А что ему мешает быть вводным словом? А точнее — использоваться в качестве вводного слова, иметь функцию вводного слова? Причем, как правило, у нас парные значения: обстоятельство — вводное слово.  Вводное слово — это не часть речи, так что способ образования указывать не надо, переход определяют пользователи языка. Обычно — детерминант? Тем лучше, вводное слово тоже в состав предложения не входит.  Можно, к примеру, поставить в начале предложения обычно + распространенное обстоятельство, которое нельзя обособить. Или что-нибудь в этом роде. Вот вам и вводное слово.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не сторонник.  Пусть себе переходят на здоровье, зачем нужны эти ограничения? У меня "действительно" буде вводным в начале доказательства исходного утверждения. Там без этого никак.